# jQuery Put not working, but works with postman

Tags: jquery, rest, api, express, put

I feel bad junking Stackoverflow with these junky questions, but with hours of looking for examples, I couldn't fix the problem.

Here it is. I am trying to PUT with jQuery, my code is this

```
$.ajax ({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/users/5a57adb130cdda747d2c4863",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  success: function() {
    console.log("worked!")
  }
})
```

The success function is called, but when I GET on postman, my data is not changed.

But when I PUT on postman, it works.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9sOa.jpg)

Thanks!!!

EDIT:

With debugging on my route, it seems as though the JS code is not passing the data properly.

Route code

```
router.put('/:id', function (req, res) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new: true}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem updating the user.");
        res.status(200).send(user);
        console.log("PUT id:" + req.params.id);
        console.log("PUT body:" + req.body.name); // .name being the data I am passing
        console.log("PUT user:" + user)


    });
});
```

Logging output

```
PUT id:5a57adb130cdda747d2c4863
PUT body:undefined
PUT user:{ _id: 5a57adb130cdda747d2c4863,
  name: 'fsafsafa',
  ... }
PUT id:5a57adb130cdda747d2c4863
PUT body:fsafsafa
PUT user:{ _id: 5a57adb130cdda747d2c4863,
  name: 'fsafsafa',
  ... }
```

Comment: Debug your server and see what data it receives when you `PUT` from `jQuery`. It's most likely a server issue and nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu okay, I will try that with conveniently placed messages on the routes.  Thanks

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu check out my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to add `router.use(bodyParser.json());` to the file!